# Why sometimes a subquery can work like using 'group by'

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and can't understand why sometimes a subquery can work like using 'group by'.

Say, there are two tables in a data base. 
'food' is a table crated by:

```
CREATE TABLE foods (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id integer,
  name text
);
```

'foods_episodes' is a table created by:

```
CREATE TABLE foods_episodes (
  food_id integer,
  episode_id integer
);
```

Now I'm using the following two sqls and generating the same result.

```
SELECT name, (SELECT count(*) FROM foods_episodes WHERE food_id=f.id) AS frequency
FROM foods AS f
ORDER BY name;

SELECT name, count(*) AS frequency
FROM foods_episodes,
     foods AS f
WHERE food_id=f.id
GROUP BY name;
```

So why the subquery in the first sql works like it group the result by name? 
When I run the subquery alone:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM foods_episodes,
     foods f
WHERE food_id=f.id
```

the result is just one row. Why using this sql as a subquery can generate multi-rows result?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: It only looks that way because in your case it looks like the `name` is unique just like `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query isn't actually grouping by `name`. If you have more than 1 record with the same name (different `ID`), you will see it being displayed twice (hence, not grouped by).

The first query uses what is called a ***correlated subquery***, it calculates the subquery (the inner `SELECT`) once *for each row of the outmost select*. Because the `FROM` in this outmost `SELECT` is just from the table `foods`, you will get one record for each food + the results of the subquery, thus no need to group.